# Using Dir.glob to list assets in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am trying to choose an image randomly from a sub directory inside my `/app/assets/images` directory using the `Dir.glob()` command, and then display it with an `image_tag`. Somehow I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
- @badges = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/badges/*")
= image_tag @badges.sample
```

Which produces the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/app/assets/images/badges/produce.png"):
```

As you can see the asset pipeline is inserting an "/assets" in front of the directory. Alright Rails, I'll meet you halfway here. So next I try removing `/app/assets` from the query path to make it work and get the following result:

```
- @badges = Dir.glob("images/badges/*")
  = image_tag @badges.sample

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets"):
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Dir.glob` is going to return images with a relative path, so your `produce.png` file will be returned as:

```
`app/assets/images/badges/produce.png`
```

However, you need to pass only the `badges/produce.png` part to `image_tag`. You need to remove the stuff before this:

```
= image_tag @badges.sample.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")
```

You may want to stick this in a helper instead:

```
def random_badge
  badges = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/badges/*")
  image_tag badges.sample.gsub("app/assets/images/", "")
end
```

and then in your view:

```
= random_badge
```